# how to prevent custom redirects on a website?

Tags: javascript

There are ways to intercept browser resource loading by using Browser Extensions (specially Google Chrome). here is the sample code:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(function (details) {

    if (details.url.includes('https://website.com/file.js')) {
        chrome.pageAction.show(details.tabId);
            return {
                redirectUrl: "https://otherwebsite.me/hackedfile.js"
            };
    }

}, {
    urls: ["<all_urls>"]
}, ["blocking"]);
```

I just want to know, how I can prevent extensions from doing it? its so annoying for me.

Comment: you can't prevent it.

Comment: @MadhawaPriyashantha woow, then its a serious problem! browser dev should consider providing ways to prevent such ways that could compromise security.

Comment: normally google will not allow this kind of a plugin to be added to there store.but rarely some malicious plugins manage to cheat google code reviews.

Comment: the thing is, some kids just pass on the extension and run it in dev mode. they often do it to hack online games. and i am facing that issue as of now.